# c++: выделение места под контейнер

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, c++14

Подскажите пожалуйста, если у меня есть контейнер и я знаю сколько в нем примерно будет элементов, для ускорения работы я могу выделить их изначально, например так:

```
std::vector<int> storage;
storage.reserve(10000);
```

а что происходит, когда я вычищаю элементы из контейнера?

```
storage.clear();
```

Нужно ли мне опять зарезервировать объем или можно ли сделать такой `clear()`, чтобы осталась зарезервированная память

Comment: Вам теоретически (тогда лучше вызвать `reserve` заново) или практически (тогда не нужно ничего делать)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `clear` не освобождает зарезервированную память. Чтобы она освободилась, нужно после `clear` вызвать `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: Это, увы, не гарантируется. По большому счету - на усмотрение реализации. Конечно, вряд ли такая реализация найдется :), но тем не менее стандарт это не гарантирует. Как не гарантирует и обратное...

Comment: @Harry - однако же [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) пишет в описании `clear`: "*Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged*". Кто-то из вас неправ.

Comment: @freim это он о shrink_to_fit, а не о clear.

Comment: Данынй ответ формально не является корректным. стандарт не гарантирует, что вызов clear() освобождает память, как не гарантирует того, что память не освобождается. Поскольку иного не оговорено, есть шанс встретить стд, где это может быть реализовано.

Comment: @freim: Это заявление сделано на основе несколько натянутой интерпретации текста стандарта, со ссылкой на SO ответ. Текст стандарта неоднозначен в этом вопросе. Так что нет, cppreference не прав, постулируя эту вольную интерпретацию как факт.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [документации по методу `std::vector::clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) (вольный перевод):

> Изменение фактического размера блока памяти не гарантируется, а потому отсутствует и гарантия изменения вместимости вектора. Для принудительного освобождения памяти необходимо использовать `swap`:
>
> ```
> vector<T>().swap(x);   // высвобождаем память из-под x
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *A reallocation is not guaranteed to happen, and the vector capacity is not guaranteed to change due to calling this function. A typical alternative that forces a reallocation is to use swap:*
>
> ```
> vector<T>().swap(x);   // clear x reallocating
> ```

Причина — дороговизна обращения к диспетчеру памяти. Ведь он должен взять глобальную блокировку, по крайней мере частично пробежаться по списку выделенных блоков и иногда выполнить слияние смежных свободных блоков.

Так что можно спокойно закладываться на то, что память повторно резервировать не надо.

Comment: скользкая формулировка на cpp). Для надежности можно после clear() вызвать reserve(), т.к. вызов reserve() с той же емкостью, что у контейнера не вызовет перевыделение памяти

Comment: @goldstar_labs Полностью согласен. Но `reserve()` — это всё же дополнительный вызов функции. Потому я и опирался на то, что по факту стандартная библиотека не будет высвобождать память в рассчёте на то, что она потребуется снова.

Comment: @goldstar_labs К тому же частые выделения и освобождения фрагментируют кучу, то есть разбивают её свободное пространство на относительно мелкие части, которые со временем всё больше уменьшаются в размере и при определённых условиях больше не могут быть выделены из-за невозможности поместить в них что-либо. И хоть подобное и недостижимо при современных объёмах памяти в типовых программах (а для нетиповых всё равно используются сторонние узкоспециализированные диспетчеры памяти), предположу, что разработчики реализаций стандартной библиотеки просто перестраховываются.

Comment: "Не гарантируется" и "не делается" - все таки разные вещи. Почему вы сделали вывод, что "можно спокойно закладываться" - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT Потому что это поведение STL по меньшей мере у GCC и MSVC. Нарушения стандарта и неопределённого поведения нет, так что можно считать это эдаким implementation-defined дополнением к гарантиям стандарта.

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужно повторно вызывать `reserve`. После очистки с помощью `clear` вектор формально считается пустым и вы не должны делать предположений о том что фактически сделал вектор с памятью. Так как стандарт ничего такого не требует и не обещает, то есть вектор может освободить всю память, ее часть или ничего не освобождать. Ничего страшного не произойдет если память не освободится, а вы повторно вызвали `reserve`. С другой стороны если память освободится, ваш повторный вызов `reserve` сделает то же что и первый - зарезервирует нужное количество памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. из всего вышесказанного все таки выходит, что если работа с контейнером идет постоянно, то можно не особо заморачиваться после вычищения контейнера с резервированием памяти, поскольку старая не отдается системе и может быть использована повторно?

Будет тот же эффект, как будто я каждый раз резервирую память, т.е. при операциях добавления элемента лишнее время на выделение памяти под элемент тратиться не будет.

Comment: Да, необходимость вмешиваться в процесс выделения памяти возникает достаточно редко. Только когда вы точно знаете потребности алгоритма и когда это действительно что-то оптимизирует.